# What is a maintainable way of trading collections of variables between functions?

Tags: matlab, design-patterns

I want to write a script `experiment.m` that will call a complicated function called `encoder(...)`.
`encoder` will involve a lot of settings that `experiment.m` is going to choose at runtime.
At some point in `experiment.m`, the settings which `encoder` will use are created as variables (in this example there are two, in real life there can be dozens):

```
blocklength = [some derivation];
bitdepth = [some derivation];
```

I create a struct that stores these values under their names:

```
encoder_settings = struct();
    encoder_settings.blocklength = blocklength;
    encoder_settings.bitdepth = bitdepth;
```

And I write my encoder function like this:

```
function encoder_out = encoder(data, encoder_settings)
    blocklength = encoder_settings.blocklength;
    bitdepth = encoder_settings.bitdepth;

    [...]
end
```

This works fine for code of moderate complexity, but after a while it becomes difficult to maintain the create-struct/load-struct blocks.

Alternatives I can think of don't seem great either:

- `encoder` is usually very complex and calling the variables directly from the struct in its body makes the code difficult to read.
- Do it dynamically using eval like this:

```
for s = fieldnames(my_struct)' eval([s{:},' = my_struct.', s{:}, ';']); end
```

Comment: I don't understand this bit: "calling the variables directly from the struct in its body makes the code difficult to read." Are you saying that using `encoder_settings.blocklength` makes it harder to read the code than just using `blocklength`? This is hard to believe. If you feel that `encoder_settings` is too long a name, make it shorter. I like to use `params`.

Comment: The bit with `eval` is going to bite you in the ass eventually. Don't do it.

Comment: I was once toled by a MathWorks trainer, that there is never a situation, where you really need `eval`. Follow @CrisLuengo and don't use it. I will be awful to debug and maintain your code as you write commands to strings and than "evaluate" it. Matlab cannot follow nested errors thrown by this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using objects for this. But structs can work fine, too. Objects have the advantage that you can do input validation on their properties, too.

Use short names for the objects/structs themselves, and keep all your variables in objects in the calling function right off the bat, instead of storing them in plain local variables first and then copying them in to an object or struct for the transfer between the two functions.

And if you're using objects, you can make the functions be methods on your objects, to organize them further.

Comment: I usually go with structs. Keep the fieldnames short to make your code more readable. You may want to create a small function that checks if your input struct has the correct structure. Use this snippet for this `ismember(fieldnames(YourStruct),{'field1','field2'}`

Comment: Also the unit of work pattern is good if the variables are unrelated but like specific to a certain context and need to go through layers. Essentially passing an object around through layers of the application.